# How to select distinct rows in a datatable and store into an array

Tags: c#, select, datatable, distinct

I have a dataset objds. objds contains a table named Table1. Table1 contains column named ProcessName. This ProcessName contains repeated names.So i want to select only distinct names.Is this possible.

```
  intUniqId[i] = (objds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ProcessName"].ToString());
```

Comment: Post sample code, from a comment you made below, it seems the answer hinges on the specifics of the query you're working with.

Answer (score 389, accepted):

```
DataView view = new DataView(table);
DataTable distinctValues = view.ToTable(true, "Column1", "Column2" ...);
```

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/153008/Select-DISTINCT-records-based-on-specified-fields

Comment: if i have 2 columns "mo" and "name" i need to get the distinct "mo" but not the distinct "name" but i need to keep the column "name" in my datatable what shall i do?

Comment: @JocelyneElKhoury, that doesn't really make sense... which value of "name" will you keep then?

Comment: @ThomasLevesque it does not matter which one...let's say i need to keep the first value of the name

Comment: OK, then you need grouping, not distinct. You could do it with Linq to DataSet: `table.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(row => row.Field<int>("mo")).Select(group => group.First()).CopyToDataTable()`

Answer (score 172):

Following single line of code will avoid the duplicate rows of a `DataTable`:

```
dataTable.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "employeeid");
```

Where:

- first parameter in `ToTable()` is a **boolean** which indicates whether you want distinct rows or not.
- second parameter in the `ToTable()` is the column name based on which we have to select distinct rows. Only these columns will be in the returned datatable.

The same can be done from a `DataSet`, by accessing a specific `DataTable`:

```
dataSet.Tables["Employee"].DefaultView.ToTable(true, "employeeid");
```

Comment: i like this answer the most, as it points to the `DefaultView` property of a `DataTable`.

Comment: What if I need to get distinct based on two columns?

Comment: @Lijo, the `ToTable(boolean, params string[] columnNames)` method allows for multiple columns to be specified.

Comment: This is magic, not even sure how it works. Saved my bacon

Answer (score 64):

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("IntValue", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("StringValue", typeof(string));
dt.Rows.Add(1, "1");
dt.Rows.Add(1, "1");
dt.Rows.Add(1, "1");
dt.Rows.Add(2, "2");
dt.Rows.Add(2, "2");

var x = (from r in dt.AsEnumerable()
        select r["IntValue"]).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 36):

With LINQ (.NET 3.5, C# 3)

```
var distinctNames = ( from row in DataTable.AsEnumerable()
 select row.Field<string>("Name")).Distinct();

 foreach (var name in distinctNames ) { Console.WriteLine(name); }
```

Answer (score 19):

You can use like that:

`data` is `DataTable`

```
data.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "Id", "Name", "Role", "DC1", "DC2", "DC3", "DC4", "DC5", "DC6", "DC7");
```

but performance will be down. try to use below code:

```
data.AsEnumerable().Distinct(System.Data.DataRowComparer.Default).ToList();
```

For Performance ; http://onerkaya.blogspot.com/2013/01/distinct-dataviewtotable-vs-linq.html

Comment: The second answer is super fast!

Answer (score 15):

```
var distinctRows = (from DataRow dRow in dtInventory.Rows
                                select dRow["column_name"] ).Distinct();

var distinctRows = (from DataRow dRow in dtInventory.Rows
                                select dRow["col1"], dRow["col2"].. ).Distinct();
```

Comment: @Adi Lester: maybe select new { col1 = dRow["col1"], col2 = dRow["col2"], ...} ).Distinct(); is more correct?

Comment: When you just have a List<DataRow> you can do this: var test = (from DataRow dRow in vm.LiveAssets select dRow["manname"]).Distinct();

Comment: The first line works.  The second, as Urik points out doesn't, but Urik's also does not work as Distinct() will not find equality when doing object-compare on anonymous types.

Answer (score 10):

To improve the above answer: The ToTable function on dataview has a "distinct" flag.

```
//This will filter all records to be distinct
dt = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(true);
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work.  There is only one overload with a distinct Boolean parameter in it and it requires the parameter array.  I think this will just return a table called "True" without any DISTINCT applied.

Comment: +1  This actually does work (at least in .NET 4.5).  If you specify the Boolean value "True" as the only parameter, it performs a DISTINCT on all columns in the DataView.

Comment: This works perfectly if you want distinct for all columns.

Answer (score 5):

Following works. I have it working for me with .NET 3.5 SP1

```
// Create the list of columns
String[] szColumns = new String[data.Columns.Count];
for (int index = 0; index < data.Columns.Count; index++)
{
    szColumns[index] = data.Columns[index].ColumnName;
}

// Get the distinct records
data = data.DefaultView.ToTable(true, szColumns);
```

Answer (score 5):

Syntax:-

```
DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.ToTable(true, "ColumnName");
```

EX:-

```
DataTable uniqueCols = dsUDFlable.Tables[0].DefaultView.ToTable(true, "BorrowerLabelName");
```

Answer (score 3):

I just happened to find this:
http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;326176#1

While looking for something similar, only, **specifically for .net 2.0**

Im assuming the OP was looking for distinct while using DataTable.Select(). (Select() doesn't support distinct)

So here is the code from the above link:

```
class DataTableHelper 
{
    public DataTable SelectDistinct(string TableName, DataTable SourceTable, string FieldName)
    {   
        DataTable dt = new DataTable(TableName);
        dt.Columns.Add(FieldName, SourceTable.Columns[FieldName].DataType);

        object LastValue = null; 
        foreach (DataRow dr in SourceTable.Select("", FieldName))
        {
            if (  LastValue == null || !(ColumnEqual(LastValue, dr[FieldName])) ) 
            {
                LastValue = dr[FieldName]; 
                dt.Rows.Add(new object[]{LastValue});
            }
        }

        return dt;
    }

    private bool ColumnEqual(object A, object B)
    {

        // Compares two values to see if they are equal. Also compares DBNULL.Value.
        // Note: If your DataTable contains object fields, then you must extend this
        // function to handle them in a meaningful way if you intend to group on them.

        if ( A == DBNull.Value && B == DBNull.Value ) //  both are DBNull.Value
            return true; 
        if ( A == DBNull.Value || B == DBNull.Value ) //  only one is DBNull.Value
            return false; 
        return ( A.Equals(B) );  // value type standard comparison
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
string[] TobeDistinct = {"Name","City","State"};
DataTable dtDistinct = GetDistinctRecords(DTwithDuplicate, TobeDistinct);

//Following function will return Distinct records for Name, City and State column.
public static DataTable GetDistinctRecords(DataTable dt, string[] Columns)
{
    DataTable dtUniqRecords = new DataTable();
    dtUniqRecords = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(true, Columns);
    return dtUniqRecords;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

it is easy

```
    DataView view = new DataView(dt);
DataTable dt2 = view.ToTable(true, "Column1", "Column2","Column3", ...,"ColumnNth");
```

and dt2 datatable contain column1,Column2..ColumnNth unique data.

Answer (score 2):

```
var ValuetoReturn = (from Rows in YourDataTable.AsEnumerable()
select Rows["ColumnName"]).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

The most simple solution is to use LINQ and then transform the result to a DataTable

```
    //data is a DataTable that you want to change
    DataTable result = data.AsEnumerable().Distinct().CopyToDataTable < DataRow > ();
```

This is valid only
for asp.net 4.0 ^ Framework and it needs the **reference to System.Data.DataSetExtensions** as Ivan Ferrer Villa pointed out

Comment: perhaps it needs the reference to `System.Data.DataSetExtensions`

Answer (score 1):

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("EMPLOYEE_LIST");

DataColumn eeCode = dt.Columns.Add("EMPLOYEE_CODE", typeof(String));
DataColumn taxYear = dt.Columns.Add("TAX_YEAR", typeof(String));
DataColumn intData = dt.Columns.Add("INT_DATA", typeof(int));
DataColumn textData = dt.Columns.Add("TEXT_DATA", typeof(String));

dt.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { eeCode, taxYear };
```

It filters data table with eecode and taxyear combinedly considered as unique

Answer (score 0):

```
objds.Table1.Select(r => r.ProcessName).AsEnumerable().Distinct();
```

Comment: Hi @GálGyula, welcome to Stack Overflow! Here we care about answers with good explanations, not just code. Only post an answer if it really solves the question and you can explain how. To improve your future answers, take a look the the guide [how do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
DataTable dtbs = new DataTable(); 
DataView dvbs = new DataView(dt); 
dvbs.RowFilter = "ColumnName='Filtervalue'"; 
dtbs = dvbs.ToTable();
```

Answer (score -2):

sthing like ?

SELECT DISTINCT .... FROM table WHERE condition

http://www.felixgers.de/teaching/sql/sql_distinct.html

note: Homework question ?  and god bless google..

http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&rlz=1C1GGLS_enJO330JO333&q=c%23+selecting+distinct+values+from+table&aq=f&oq=&aqi=

Comment: to whomever downvoted me :S,, obviously the question was modified after my answer ?? (answer 10:15, question edited on 12:15 ) oh well.. thx for ur ignorance :)

Comment: OP asks for how to select distinct rows in a C# ado.net environment, not in an actual database.