# How i Get Distinct record from DataSet?

Tags: c#

I have a Static Dataset and i want to Distinct Records from this DataSet how is it possible?

Comment: Yep, please correct the title for searching purposes, ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here: [How to select distinct rows in a datatable and store into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199176/how-to-select-distinct-values-from-datatable)

Answer (score 0):

[This link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetdataset/thread/ed9c6a6a-a93e-4bf5-a892-d8471b84aa3b/) suggests this code to get distinct values from a DataTable:

```
DataTable distinctTable = originalTable.DefaultView.ToTable(true);
```

The "true" argument in ToTable() method means it gets distinct values.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can also go the LINQ route by using the LINQ to DataSet extensions:

```
using System.Data;

class Program {

  static DataTable dtPosts = new DataTable();

  static void Main(string[] args) {
    //some work here to fill the table, etc.

    //select distinct rows, and only two fields from those rows...
    var rows = (from p in dtPosts.AsEnumerable()
            select new
            {
                Title = p.Field<string>("Title"),
                Body = p.Field<string>("Body")
            }).Distinct();

    Console.WriteLine("Select distinct count = {0}", rows.Count());
    Console.ReadLine();
  }
}
```

Depends on what you want to do.  Thought I add it to the thread.  Hope it helps!