# Selected columns from DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

How to get the Selected columns form the DataTable? 
For e.g my BaseTable has three columns, 
ColumnA, 
ColumnB and 
ColumnC. 
Now as part of intermediate operations, I need to retrieve all the rows only from the ColumnA. Is there any predefined formula just like **DataTable.Select?**

Comment: What would be the purpose of pulling only one column?  If you leave all three columns there, you can always take just the first column with `DataTable.Rows[i]["ColumnA"]` when you are looping through data.

Comment: I need to set the distinct row values of Column-A into a listBox.

Comment: I can create a DataView and eliminate the unnecessary columns from there. But its a two-step procedure and chokes if the datatable size is huge.

Comment: DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
DataTable dtColA = dv.ToTable(true, new string[] { "Column-A" });

Comment: What .NET framework are you using?  Is LINQ an option for you?

Comment: I need for FrameWork 2.0

Comment: @Murali: Can you add the distinct values part into your question?  Otherwise your question doesn't make sense.  Thanks :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[DataView.ToTable Method.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wec2b2e6.aspx)

```
DataView view = new DataView(MyDataTable);
DataTable distinctValues = view.ToTable(true, "ColumnA");
```

Now you can select.

```
DataRow[] myRows = distinctValues.Select();
```

Comment: I used the similar one which I already posted in the comments. It works fine for me. Just looking for any other better solution which doesn't effects the performance. Anyways I am OK with this for now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

From this question: [How to select distinct rows in a datatable and store into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199176/how-to-select-distinct-values-from-datatable) you can get the distinct values:

```
DataView view = new DataView(table);
DataTable distinctValues = view.ToTable(true, "ColumnA");
```

If you're dealing with a large DataTable and care about the performance, I would suggest something like the following in .NET 2.0.  I'm assuming the type of the data you're displaying is a string so please change as necessary.

```
Dictionary<string,string> colA = new Dictionary<string,string>();
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows) {
    colA[(string)row["ColumnA"]] = "";
}
return colA.Keys;
```

Comment: Minimum number of rows will be around 50K and this should be implemented for all the 26 columns. So foreach, for and while loops are out of question.

Comment: Anyways, the above solution works for me. I am sure your solution will be perfect for the small data objects.