# Returning all duplicated rows in C#

Tags: c#

Name              City           ID

C                Houston        12
A                London         36
B                Houston        25
A                London         40

Output:

A                London         36
A                London         40

I have a DataTable and want to return all duplicate rows (only based on Name and City columns)
Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10707031/determining-duplicates-in-a-datatable

Comment: What have you tried? If you need a starting point, just look at LINQ methods and check the doc for those that may apply (like Intersect).

Answer (score 2):

You can run the LINQ statement below

```
var l = (from r in table
         group r by new { a.Name, a.City } into g
         where g.Count() > 1
         select g).SelectMany(g => g).ToList();
```