# DataTable.Select() Distinct then add values

Tags: c#

I just need to SELECT Distinct values from columnA then ADD the values that has joined to columnB

Sample:

```
columnA    |    columnB
A                3
B                4
A                3
A                2 
B                1
C                3
```

Result:

```
columnA        |    columnB
A                    8
B                    5
C                    3
```

i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199176/how-to-select-distinct-values-from-datatable) but it just have the array of column names as parameter.

is there any other way or a sample using DataTable.Select()

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

You can use [LINQ-to-DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977.aspx) and [`Enumerable.GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304.aspx):

```
var colAGroups = tbl.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(row => row.Field<String>("ColumnA"))
                .Select(grp => new
                {
                    Value = grp.Key,
                    Sum = grp.Sum(row => row.Field<int>("ColumnB"))
                });

foreach (var colAGroup in colAGroups)
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} {1}", colAGroup.Value, colAGroup.Sum));
}
```