# How do you get rid off duplicate entries in a data table using C#?

Tags: c#, dataset, duplicates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to select distinct values from datatable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199176/how-to-select-distinct-values-from-datatable)

Here is my code that I'm currently working on. I'm trying to get rid off the duplicated fields in my Dataset. I believe the correct way of doing this is by an If statement. Can anyone help please? This is the code I have so far:

Comment: Can assign UNIQUE in database fields.

Answer (score 2):

> There is this DataView method called ToTable with two parameters: (and a three-parameter    overloaded version)
>
> a boolean param distinct 
>     If true, the returned System.Data.DataTable contains rows that have distinct values for    all its columns. The default value is false.
>
> a string array param columnNames 
>     A string array that contains a list of the column names to be included in the returned     System.Data.DataTable. The System.Data.DataTable contains the specified columns in the   order they appear within this array.

```
// create a dv from the source dt 
 DataView dv = new DataView(dt); 
// set the output columns array of the destination dt 
 string[] strColumns = {"NodeID", "Title", "Url"}; 
// true = yes, i need distinct values. 
 dt = dv.ToTable(true, strColumns);
```

reference :
[Remove Duplicate Records in a DataTable the Easy Way](http://dengkefu.com/blog/programming/c-sharp-and-dot-net/remove-duplicate-records-in-a-datatable-the-easy-way.html)

Answer (score 0):

Every time I need uniqueness I use HashSet instead of other structures. So the short answer is :I don't.

Hashset has a nice feature of letting you decide what it thinks is unique - just use the appropriate constructor.

Another thing is - if you're not using DataSets to access the database - don't use it, and if you do then use the strongly typed version instead. This of course does not apply if you have good reasons to do so - it's just a general rule.