# c# all distincts value from datatable

Tags: c#, datatable, dataview

I've found this piece of code that can be used to get all distinct values. But my datatable has 10 columns. The distinctValues only shows the columns I write in the toTable(); Is it possible to use this function, but also show the rest of the columns?

```
DataView view = new DataView(table);
DataTable distinctValues = view.ToTable(true, "Column1", "Column2");
```

Comment: When you say show the rest of the columns and they were different how would they then be distinct?

Comment: Which row do you want to see when there are multiple rows with the same fields, just the first, all or a special one?

Comment: See this thread

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199176/how-to-select-distinct-values-from-datatable

Answer (score 1):

Unless those columns you mention are the full key to the table, there is no guarantee that for a particular combination of those two columns the other columns will have exactly one value.

And if they *were* the key, then there would be no need to use a "distinct" filter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Linq-To-DataTable`

```
var distinct = from row in table.AsEnumerable()
               group row by new
               {
                   Col1 = row.Field<string>("Column1"),
                   Col2 = row.Field<string>("Column2")
               } into Group
               select Group.First()
DataTable tblDistinct = distinctRows.CopyToDataTable();
```

(assuming that you just want an arbitrary row[the first])