# Remove duplicate web application names from foreach loop

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

i am new to sharepoint. Can someone tell me how to remove duplicate webapplication names from my code below:

```
SPFarm farm = SPFarm.Local;
                SPWebService webser = farm.Services.GetValue<SPWebService>("");
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("Port Numbers", typeof(string));

                foreach (SPWebApplication spwebApp in webser.WebApplications)
                {
                    foreach (SPSite site in spwebApp.Sites)
                    {
                        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                        dr[0] = site.WebApplication.Name;
                        dr[1] = site.Port;
                        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                    }
                }

                this.GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                this.GridView1.DataBind();
```

Help Highly Appreciated!

i want to display only one name with one port number in the grid.
for instance if there are five sites on web application port no. 2222 it displays 5 times webapplication name with port number 2222. I want it only once.

Comment: Got the answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199176/how-to-select-distinct-values-from-datatable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DataView view = new DataView(dt);
dt = view.ToTable(true, "Name", "Port Numbers");
```