# Distinct records in DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, dataset

I want to get distinct records based on some fields. I'm using the following method:

```
string[] TobeDistinct = { "PKID" };
DataTable dtDistinct = GetDistinctRecords(ds.Tables[0], TobeDistinct);
DataSet ds2 = new System.Data.DataSet();
ds2.Tables.Add(dtDistinct);

public static DataTable GetDistinctRecords(DataTable dt, string[] Columns)
{
    DataTable dtUniqRecords = new DataTable();
    dtUniqRecords = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(true, Columns);
    return dtUniqRecords;
}
```

This gives me the distinct records, but only two records come. Only two distinct PKID will come. For example, I have multiple records with PKID 10,12,14,16, but the result is 2 rows with PKID 10 and 12. More two rows are not there, but should be there. What do I need to do?

I follow this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/153008/Select-DISTINCT-records-based-on-specified-fields

[image]

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem. Are you sure that you are passing the right table to the GetDistinctRecords?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select distinct rows in a datatable and store into an array.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199176/how-to-select-distinct-rows-in-a-datatable-and-store-into-an-array)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use like follows

```
DataView view = new DataView(table);
DataTable distinctValues = view.ToTable(true, "Column1", "Column2" ...);
```

More detail
[How to select distinct rows in a datatable and store into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199176/how-to-select-distinct-values-from-datatable)

Comment: it doesn't effect at all! same two rows result. What i'm missing sir?

Comment: there will be some leading or trailing space in between try `trim function` while selecting the record form the database

Comment: it may be due to space in between. actually i don't have empty field record in pkid.

Answer (score 6):

Can you try this?

```
var myResult = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(c => (DataRow)c["MyColumn"]).Distinct().ToList();
```