# using distinct in DataTable.Select function

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a data table and I want to populate two extra datatables using this datatable,here is a simple form of my table

```
My data table columns are 
[name][family][id][propertyid][propertyEnergy]
John smith 1 12 Gas
John smith 1 13 Gas
John smith 1 14 null
John smith 1 15 Gas
Hannah smith 2 16 Gas
Hannah smith 2 17 Gas
Hannah smith 2 18 Gas
```

I want to use this query in datatable `select distinct [name][family][id] from table`
which results

```
John smith 1
Hannah smith 2
```

and again I use this query in another datatable `select [id][propertyid][propertyEnergy] from table` which results

```
1 12 Gas
1 13 Gas
1 14 null
1 15 Gas
2 16 Gas
2 17 Gas
2 18 Gas
```

I searched and found that I can `DataTable.Select` but examples that I have seen shows that I can only add Where sentense to  `DataTable.Select` and I have no idea how to perform things like `Distinct` in it,
Can you please help me or give me some hints how to do it?
Thank you so much

Comment: Helpful link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199176/how-to-select-distinct-rows-in-a-datatable-and-store-into-an-array

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `Linq-To-DataTable` instead:

```
var distinctNames = table.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(row => new
    {
        Name = row.Field<string>("Name"),
        Family = row.Field<string>("Family"),
        ID = row.Field<int>("ID")
    })
    .Distinct();

var distinctProperties = table.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(row => new
    {
        ID = row.Field<int>("ID"),
        PropertyID = row.Field<int>("PropertyID"),
        PropertyEnergy = row.Field<int>("PropertyEnergy")
    })
    .Distinct();
```

If you need two additional `DataTables` you have to create and fill them manually since the columns are different than the main-table. You can fill them in a loop from the queries above.

This should work as it is:

```
string[] nameColumns = { "Name", "Family", "ID" };
DataTable tblNames = table.Clone();
var removeColumns = tblNames.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
    .Where(c => !nameColumns.Contains(c.ColumnName)).ToList();
removeColumns.ForEach(c => tblNames.Columns.Remove(c));
foreach (var x in distinctNames)
    tblNames.Rows.Add(x.Name, x.Family, x.ID);

string[] propertyColumns = { "ID", "PropertyID", "PropertyEnergy" };
DataTable tblProperties = table.Clone();
removeColumns = tblProperties.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
    .Where(c => !propertyColumns.Contains(c.ColumnName)).ToList();
removeColumns.ForEach(c => tblProperties.Columns.Remove(c));
foreach (var x in distinctProperties)
    tblProperties.Rows.Add(x.ID, x.PropertyID, x.PropertyEnergy);
```

Comment: Wouldn´t this also require an `EqualityComprarer` within `Distinct` to ignore the multiples?

Comment: @HimBromBeere: no, because anonymous types have it already built-in. The `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods on anonymous types are defined in terms of the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods of the properties, two instances of the same anonymous type are equal only if all their properties are equal. Note that the order matters.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thank you for your great help..Is table my datatable?I used it but it says does not contain defintion for it..What should I write instead var in code?

Comment: @MajidHojati: yes, table is your table :)

Comment: @TimSchmelter So why I get this error Error 20 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<AnonymousType#1>' does not contain a definition for 'Distinct' and no extension method 'Distinct' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<AnonymousType#1>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @MajidHojati: have you added `using System.Linq;` at the top of the file?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thanks..It was my mistake,Sorry.it fixed,But Why distinctNames  does not have anything when I run it,It is empty,,

Comment: @MajidHojati: how have you checked it? Have you used the code below to create the datatable or do you have checked `distinctNames` in the debugger? User `distinctNames.ToList()` if you want to create a list of this anonymous type. It's impossible that it's empty if the DataTable contains rows.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thank you for your help,It is great..I managed to find the problem..It was about casting columns to wrong type