# how to show Products uniquely in list stored in session

Tags: c#

This is my code to show data in list in a grid .It shows data but also duplicate tha products . So, Please suggest me a way to show products uniquely.For Example
if I am adding a new product to cart it duplicate the products previously added products

```
private List<Cart> PopulateData()
{

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();       
    dt = (DataTable)Session["Test"];

    List<Cart> Product = new List<Cart>();

    if (Session["key"] == null)
    {

       foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
       {
           string Quantity = Request.QueryString["Quantity"];

           float f_num = float.Parse(row["ProductPrice"].ToString());
           Cart cr = new Cart();
           Product.Add(new Cart { ProductName = row["ProductName"].ToString(), ProductPrice = f_num, Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(Quantity), Type = row["Type"].ToString() });
       }

   }
   else if(Session["key"]!=null)
   {
       Product = (List<Cart>)Session["key"];
       foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
       {
           string Quantity = Request.QueryString["Quantity"];

           float f_num = float.Parse(row["ProductPrice"].ToString());
           Cart cr = new Cart();
           Product.Add(new Cart { ProductName = row["ProductName"].ToString(), ProductPrice = f_num, Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(Quantity), Type = row["Type"].ToString() });
       }

   }
   Session["key"] = Product;
    return Product;
}
```

Comment: Find this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199176/how-to-select-distinct-rows-in-a-datatable-and-store-into-an-array

Comment: @Praveen Not sure of the question. you want to store only unique items in the Session?

Comment: hi Junaid I want to bind unique data in my gridview . my code just duplicate previously added data.

Comment: So the return product should only return unique elements. That calls for linq then if you can't make sure that you add only not already existing elements. do you have any fieldname that tells that these products are the same?

Answer (score 0):

in the else part, (where you have added data from session) you have to check if the row is in the session then do not add it in your `product` class based on some 'uniqueid'.

```
 else {
   Product = (List<Cart>)Session["key"];
   foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
   {
       string Quantity = Request.QueryString["Quantity"];
       var uniqueid = Convert.ToInt32(row["productId"]);
       //Linq to find if the product list has the same item
       bool containsItem = Product.Any(item => item.ProductId == uniqueid); 
       var uniqueid = Convert.ToInt32(row["uniqueId"]);

       bool containsItem = Product.Any(item => item.UniqueProperty == uniqueid); 
       float f_num = float.Parse(row["ProductPrice"].ToString());
       Cart cr = new Cart();
       if(containsItem) {
       Product.Add(new Cart { ProductName = row["ProductName"].ToString(), ProductPrice = f_num, Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(Quantity), Type = row["Type"].ToString() });
      }
   }
}
```

Edit: code is changed now. Check the proper Productid property and field name

Comment: it gives error in following line Plz suggest how to resolve the error -----  bool containsItem = Product.Any(item => item.UniqueProperty == uniqueid);

Comment: `UniqueProperty` is the name of your unique id (product key or something)
uniqueid is some uniqueid you have in the record
You have to construct the same logic based on the unique id you have there. dont just copy paste the code

Comment: I am new to c# so please suggest me according to my code what should I take UniqueProperty

Comment: Do you have a unique id field (like 'product id' )in the `Product` class? if yes then use it instead of 'uniqueid' in the code.

Comment: No! do you have product id or a primary key you have used for the product table?

Comment: it gives error that cart does not contain a defination for UniqueProperty and no extension method 'UniqueProperty ' accepting first argument of type cart could be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly referrence)

Comment: I am unable to get what are you trying to say how I can change from ProductId will you please say

Comment: do you have product id field in product class??

Comment: yes  I have product id and wrote code in following manner bool containsItem = Product.Any(item => item.UniqueProperty == ProductID);

Comment: ok.. code is changed now. Check the proper Productid property and field name. check the code above.

Answer (score 0):

At the time you assign Product list to session you can simple Distinct records using linq query

at this line

```
    Session["key"] = Product;
```

you can either do it like

```
Session["key"] = Product.GroupBy(x => new { x.Quantity, x.ProductName, x.ProductPrice }).Select(x=>x.Key).ToList();
```

Or

```
Session["key"] = Product.Select(x => new { Quantity = x.Quantity, ProductName=x.ProductName, ProductPrice=x.ProductPrice }).Distinct();
```

Comment: I tried both but it gives error . So, please suggest hoe to overcome it.

Comment: @Ruchir--Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType0`3[System.Int32,System.String,System.Single]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Cart]'----this is error that it showing plz help

Comment: You need to cast your object as shown below:

   `Session["key"] = Product.GroupBy(x => new { x.ProductId, x.ProductName }).Select(x => new Cart {ProductId = x.Key.ProductId,ProductName = x.Key.ProductName }).ToList();`

Comment: You cast it in `Select()`