# Merge duplicate row in one with other column in c#

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a `DataTable` that contain duplicate row with difference value in one column. like this:

[image]

So, I want merge duplicate `PersonId` in one row where `PersonId` and `OrginalDate` and `ConvertedDate` is same. like this:

[image]

**It is possible that one person has even more records in one date**

**Update:**

**Note: I don't want delete duplicate records. If you pay close attention to the photos, I want to merge duplicate records into another table with more columns**

Comment: Cool task description. What is your question?

Comment: How to make the second table from the first table?

Comment: @Filburt The second table is different from the first table. I want to merge the records of the first table into the second table. Just like second image

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select distinct rows in a datatable and store into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199176/how-to-select-distinct-rows-in-a-datatable-and-store-into-an-array)

Comment: @Filburt Unfortunately not. I explained more in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer

```
var groups = dataTable.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(row => new
 {
   PersonId = row.Field<double>("PersonId"),
   OrginalDate = row.Field<double>("OrginalDate")
 });

var maxItems = groups.Max(x => x.Count()) / 2;
DataTable pivot= new DataTable();
pivot.Columns.Add("PersonId", typeof(int));
pivot.Columns.Add("OrginalDate", typeof(int));
pivot.Columns.Add("GregorianConvertedDate", typeof(DateTime));
pivot.Columns.Add("PersianConvertedDate", typeof(string));

for (int i = 1; i <= maxItems; i++)
{
  pivot.Columns.Add("EnterTime" + i, typeof(TimeSpan));
  pivot.Columns.Add("ExitTime" + i, typeof(TimeSpan));
}

foreach (var group in groups)
{
  DataRow newRow = tempDataTable.Rows.Add();
  newRow["PersonId"] = group.First()["PersonId"];
  newRow["OrginalDate"] = group.First()["OrginalDate"];
  newRow["GregorianConvertedDate"] = group.First()["GregorianConvertedDate"];
  newRow["PersianConvertedDate"] = group.First()["PersianConvertedDate"];

  for (int i = 0; i < group.Count() / 2; i++)
  {
    newRow["EnterTime" + (i + 1)] = group.Skip(2 * i).First().Field<string>("ConvertedTime");
    newRow["ExitTime" + (i + 1)] = group.Skip((2 * i) + 1).First().Field<string>("ConvertedTime");
   }
}
```

Many thanks to [@jdweng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5015238/jdweng)

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Personid", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("OrginalDate", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("ConvertedDate", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.ColumnsAdd("OriginalTime", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("ConvertedTime", typeof(TimeSpan));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 115, 45099, DateTime.Parse("6/22/2023 12:00:00"), 1206, TimeSpan.Parse("12:06") });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 115, 45099, DateTime.Parse("6/22/2023 12:00:00"), 1859, TimeSpan.Parse("18:59") });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 631, 45099, DateTime.Parse("6/22/2023 12:00:00"), 1449, TimeSpan.Parse("14:49") });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 631, 45099, DateTime.Parse("6/22/2023 12:00:00"), 1722, TimeSpan.Parse("17:22") });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 631, 45099, DateTime.Parse("6/22/2023 12:00:00"), 1819, TimeSpan.Parse("18:19") });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 631, 45099, DateTime.Parse("6/22/2023 12:00:00"), 2006, TimeSpan.Parse("20:06") });

            var groups = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<int>("Personid"));

            var maxItems = groups.Max(x => x.Count()) / 2;

            DataTable pivot = new DataTable();
            pivot.Columns.Add("Personid", typeof(int));
            pivot.Columns.Add("OrginalDate", typeof(int));
            pivot.Columns.Add("ConvertedDate", typeof(DateTime));

            for (int i = 1; i <= maxItems; i++)
            {
                pivot.Columns.Add("EnterTime" + i, typeof(TimeSpan));
                pivot.Columns.Add("ExitTime" + i, typeof(TimeSpan));
            }

            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                DataRow newRow = pivot.Rows.Add();
                newRow["Personid"] = group.First()["Personid"];
                newRow["OrginalDate"] = group.First()["OrginalDate"];
                newRow["ConvertedDate"] = group.First()["ConvertedDate"];
                for(int i = 0; i < group.Count() / 2; i++)
                {
                    newRow["EnterTime" + (i + 1)] = group.Skip(2 * i).First().Field<TimeSpan>("ConvertedTime");
                    newRow["ExitTime" + (i + 1)] = group.Skip((2 *i) + 1).First().Field<TimeSpan>("ConvertedTime");
                }
            }


        }
```

Results

[image]

Comment: Your code looks correct, but the ‍‍‍```maxItems``` value is not calculated correctly in the main table. It should be 4 or 6 in the end, which calculates 32, can you help me fix it?
This piece of code is also wrong: ‍‍‍

```for (int i = 0; i < group.Count() / 2; i++)
                {
                    newRow["EnterTime" + (i + 1)] = group.Skip(2 * i).First().Field<string>("ConvertedTime");
                    newRow["ExitTime" + (i + 1)] = group.Skip((2 * i) + 1).First().Field<string>("ConvertedTime");
                }```

Comment: The max value is divided by 2 and is the max of any grouped item.   The calculations are easy if you divided the count by 2.  I then multiply the count by 2 to get the even rows (enter time) and odd rows (exit time).  The code gets the correct values you posted in the question. You posted answer may be wrong. Applications like this usually the exit time of one row is the enter time of next row. Your answer the input alternates between one row being the enter time and next row the exit time.